# Apache htaccess RewriteRule to remove trailing slash; infinite loop?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, regex

I use the following in `.htaccess` (`mod_rewrite`) to remove the trailing slash from my URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/$ $1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Of course, since the character class doesn't match a slash, this works fine for links like `some_page/`, but not `article/some_page/`.

If I add a slash to the character class to make `[a-z0-9_/-]`, I get an infinite loop when trying to load the page. I also tried making the `+` non-greedy by using `+?`, but that didn't work either; neither did removing the `R=301` redirect.

(If it makes a difference, the page to load, `/article/some_page/` is actually `/article/some_page/index.html`, I just want it to appear as `/article/some_page`.)

Answer (score 1):

> If it makes a difference

Yes it does. Apache (mod_dir) will send back a redirect if you pass a URL that maps to a directory without a trailing '/', e.g.

```
[colinm@example ~]$ curl -I http://localhost/somedir
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2011 11:48:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Location: http://localhost/somedir/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: OK, so there's nothing I can do then to remove the trailing slash in this case?

Comment: You can turn off mod_dir's redirect by including a `DirectorySlash Off`